# How do I delete files using absolute path in ant?

Tags: ant, fileset, installanywhere

I want to delete all the files of certain type in in a folder.  However, I only have the absolute path to the folder.  What can I do?

For example, I might want to delete on the .txt files in C:\example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="deletetxtfiles" name="Deletefiles">
    <target name="deletetxtfiles">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="C:/Example" includes="*.txt"/>            
        </delete>
    </target> 
</project>
```

It deletes only txt files from C:\Example. Folders, other file types or txt files in subfolders will not be affected.

Comment: If I were to run this ant task from C:\ant_project_home. Wouldn't the files I delete be C:\ant_project_home\C:\Example\\*.txt

Comment: I think there has to be something to convert from relative path to absolute path.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm calling ant from C:\antexample. This folder contains the build.xml. It deletes the files in C:\example.

Comment: Ant can detect drive letters and whether something is an absolute path. Because `/` is right after the drive letter, Ant knows it's an absolute path.